# iOS WebView - Open link in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, webview, sfsafariviewcontroller

So I am trying to detect a link click within a webView and then present this url in the new `SFSafariViewController` however am having some issues.

Anyone got any ideas?

This is what I am currently doing:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html");
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest);

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadInView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) {

        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked){
            let url = request.URL;

                let sfViewController = SFSafariViewController(URL:url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)

                self.presentViewController(sfViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                    print("May the force be with you!")
                })
        }

    }

}
```